# Прямая речь и знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Служащие в итоговой справке отмечают следующее: "Полученное образование не соответствует преподаваемому предмету" -- и требуют обязательного соответствия.

Нужно ли это понимать как прямую речь? Если да, тогда постановка тире верна...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, это схема  А: «П» - а. Она применяется в том случае. если на месте разрыва слов автора нет знака препинания или находится союз И, например: Со словами: «Прощайте и будьте здоровы» – он вышел из комнаты. Николай думал: «Неужели французы?» – и смотрел на них, не веря глазам. Тире здесь обозначает паузу в речи.

Интересно, что для схемы А-П-А возможны варианты и с отсутствием тире. В этом случае разрыв слов автора делается на месте запятой, и тогда прямая речь как бы встраивается в предложение:Когда вы мне ответили: «Этого не может быть», значило ли это никогда? Отец Василий сказал: «Да,  вот так», вздохнул, помолчал и ушёл.Пробормотав: «Барчуки проклятые», он закурил сигару и плотнее завернулся в шинель. В этих предложениях прямая речь не влияет на общую интонацию, специальная пауза отсутствует.

Answer (score 2):

Это цитирование, оформленное как прямая речь. Постановка тире верна:после прямой речи продолжение предложения

Comment: @Людмила! А нельзя ли перед администраторами сайта походатайстовать об открытии третьего форума - по истории. Он, по-моему, очень востребован в массах. Правда, есть опасения, что его прихлопнут в зародыше за разгул страстей... Боюсь, что Вы подумаете: "А что же ты, Заяц, сам не обратишься, куда надо?" Отвечаю: сроду не любил ходить по инстанциям - из-за своего косноязычия и близорукости мысли. А Вы - любите людей и умеете убеждать.

Comment: Спасибо за комплимент, конечно,но убедить можно в том, что является ТВОИМ убеждением. Несерьёзно будет, если по моей просьбе будет открыт форум,а я туда ни разу не войду, что так и  будет  - несведуща в вопросах истории. Вы преуменьшаете свои возможности.Ваше предложение просто разместите на форуме МЕТА внизу страницы (последний форум).Думаю, Вас многие поддержат.

Comment: Вы и сами убедились, насколько я близорук, не поставив себя в Ваше положение... А где, как искать этот форум МЕТА? С помощью Поисковика?

Comment: Опустите взгляд на самый низ этой страницы, увидите:о сайте, справка, блог ,связаться с нами, оставить отзыв ,соглашение - можно нажать на "оставить отзыв" - попадёте на Мету, а можно во второй строке нажать на надпись "мета".

Comment: Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @русак, хоть и нет никакой чести в том, чтобы поддерживать разговор, предмет которого не имеет никакого отношения к тематике форума, я все же поспешу сообщить Вам благую весть о том, что я избавила Вас от необходимости "ходить по инстанциям" и сама внесла предложение о создании нового форума [здесь][1].


  [1]: http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/2078/предложение-исторический-форум

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, @Noir! Я выразил Вам соответствующее признание там, где Вы внесли предложение, а тут даже расщедрился до "огромного спасибо". (Извините, я всё время, встречая Ваш ник, думал, что Вы - мужчина. Я полон презрения к самому себе: не узнать женщину??? - не достойно мужчины!!!) Ещё раз - благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Людмилой. Это случай обрамления прямой речи (в данном случае - цитаты) словами автора. "...Она сказала: "Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками" - и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку" (Л.Т.). - тире перед союзом "и" при однородных сказуемых" ([Источник](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.5)).

Comment: @Noir! Очень поддерживаю Вашу инициативу об историческом форуме!

Comment: @Noir! Огромное спасибо Вам за благую весть! (пишу уже после Вашего сообщения. Пока я раздумывал, как всегда, боясь,  высовываться "на люди", Вы, смелая женщина, решительно заявили, что Вам нужен форум, и за это получИте мою вторую благодарность). Стыдно признаваться, что я такой, но я - хороший, вообще-то говоря, хотя женщины меня не любят, как и гусекрада Паниковского.